# Highcharts Gauge example does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to use the stock standard Highcharts Gauge example and I keep getting a blank page.  When I copy the code back into jsfiddle - I still get a blank page! (The weird part is I copied the code from the example on jsfiddle in the first place!)

Can someone please tell me what's going on here??

Link to my test page here:  [Test page](http://www.sesupply.co.nz/test2.htm)

jsfiddle page here:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eybsrsy/)

When I look at the console I get the following errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined`

`Uncaught TypeError: k.getOptions is not a function`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of undefined`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

```
$(function () {

$('#gauge_container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Have you added the jQuery script reference?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9eybsrsy/1/  Yep, jQuery is missing

Comment: @Satyajit - thanks for that, as you can tell I'm a complete noob with this stuff.
I've added the following lines to the html, but I still get the same result!

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Can you tell me how to add the jQuery script reference?

Comment: OK, problem solved!  It seems I was adding the wrong reference.

Answer (score -1):

Gauge is not defined

```js
 <script src="../Assets/JS/nprogress.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/skycons.js"></script>

    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/curvedLines.js"></script>

     <script src="../Assets/JS/date.js"></script>

    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>


    <script src="../Assets/JS/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/JS/daterangepicker.js"></script>

    <script src="../Assets/JS/custom.min.js"></script>
    
    
    that is code that i am using in asp.net web form.
        <!-- gauge.js -->
    <script>
      var opts = {
          lines: 12,
          angle: 0,
          lineWidth: 0.4,
          pointer: {
              length: 0.75,
              strokeWidth: 0.042,
              color: '#1D212A'
          },
          limitMax: 'false',
          colorStart: '#1ABC9C',
          colorStop: '#1ABC9C',
          strokeColor: '#F0F3F3',
          generateGradient: true
      };
      var target = document.getElementById('foo'), gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts);
      gauge.maxValue = 6000;
      gauge.animationSpeed = 32;
      gauge.set(3200);
      gauge.setTextField(document.getElementById("gauge-text"));
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this a solution for the question asked by SESupply?